# UI Virtualization of GridView and ListView in HubSection

Tags: windows-10, uwp, windows-10-universal

I just noticed that if I put a GridView or ListView in UWP app inside a HubSection, the UI Virtualization breaks. Is my understanding correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Virtualization only happens for items outside the viewport. So it's important to place your `GridView` into a control that limits its size (e.g. `Grid` without auto-sized rows/columns) or set the size of the control. Wouldn't surprise me if your `HubSection` doesn't have a fixed size.

> The concept of a viewport is critical to UI virtualization because the
>   framework must create the elements that are likely to be shown. In
>   general, the viewport of an ItemsControl is the extent of the logical
>   control. For example, the viewport of a ListView is the width and
>   height of the ListView element. Some panels allow child elements
>   unlimited space, examples being ScrollViewer and a Grid, with
>   auto-sized rows or columns. When a virtualized ItemsControl is placed
>   in a panel like that, it takes enough room to display all of its
>   items, which defeats virtualization. Restore virtualization by setting
>   a width and height on the ItemsControl.

[image]

Also custom templates often break virtualization:

> If you provide a custom items panel template (see ItemsPanel) then
>   make sure you use a virtualizing panel such as ItemsWrapGrid or
>   ItemsStackPanel. If you use VariableSizedWrapGrid, WrapGrid, or
>   StackPanel, then you will not get virtualization.

More info on MSDN: [UWP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/optimize-gridview-and-listview) and [Win8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh780657.aspx), which also has some good points that still count.