# UWP ListView's SelectedItem is reset when the ListView is in other ListView with large data

Tags: c#, listview, uwp

When large ListView's DataTemplate contains small ListView, small ListView's SelectedItem is reset.
I've made sample application which select each person's country from three choices.
I've selected "India" at last small ListView item(index:999) from code behind.
But when I scroll down, nothing is selected and the debug log is as below.

[Debug log]

Added: India, Removed:

Added:, Removed: India

[MainPage.xaml]

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind People}" SelectionMode="None">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Person">
            <StackPanel BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1">
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Country, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                <ListView x:Name="CountryList"
                            ItemsSource="{x:Bind Countries, Mode=OneWay}"
                            SelectedItem="{x:Bind Country, Mode=TwoWay}"
                            SelectionChanged="CountryList_SelectionChanged">
                </ListView>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

[MainPage.xaml.cs]

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    GenerateSampleData();
}

private void GenerateSampleData()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        People.Add(new Person
        {
            Countries = new List<string> { "China", "India", "USA" },
        });
    }
    People[999].Country = "India";
}

private void CountryList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Added:");
    foreach (var added in e.AddedItems)
    {
        if (added is string country)
        {
            sb.Append($" {country,-5}");
        }
    }

    sb.Append(", Removed:");
    foreach (var removed in e.RemovedItems)
    {
        if (removed is string country)
        {
            sb.Append($" {country,-5}");
        }
    }
    Debug.WriteLine(sb);
}
```

Complete source is below.
 https://github.com/tokane888/ListViewQuestion

And I'm not sure it relates but some small ListView is shown gray like below.
(I didn't touch this small ListView even from code behind or by hand.)
[image: Gray ListView]

Answer (score 0):

1. The reason your `ListView` item is not getting selected is that you are setting your property before the `ListView` is actually loaded. Better to set selected item in the `ListView` `Loaded` event.
2. You are seeing a gray area is because of the `ListView` virtualization as your `ListView` contains a large number of data.

In order to fix both the issue, please modify your code as below:

XAML:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind People}" SelectionMode="None">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Person">
                    <StackPanel BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1">
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Country, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                        <ListView x:Name="CountryList"
                                    ItemsSource="{x:Bind Countries, Mode=OneWay}"
                                    SelectedItem="{x:Bind Country, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                    SelectionChanged="CountryList_SelectionChanged"
                                    Loaded="CountryList_Loaded"
                                  >
                            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <VirtualizingStackPanel/>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                        </ListView>

                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Code behind:

```
 public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Person> People { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
            GenerateSampleData();
        }

        private void GenerateSampleData()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                People.Add(new Person
                {
                    Countries = new List<string> { "China", "India", "USA" },
                });
            }

        }

        private void CountryList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Added:");
            foreach (var added in e.AddedItems)
            {
                if (added is string country)
                {
                    sb.Append($" {country,-5}");
                }
            }

            sb.Append(", Removed:");
            foreach (var removed in e.RemovedItems)
            {
                if (removed is string country)
                {
                    sb.Append($" {country,-5}");
                }
            }
            Debug.WriteLine(sb);
        }

        private void CountryList_Loaded(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           People[999].Country = "India";
        }
    }
```

Also please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38994536/ui-virtualization-of-gridview-and-listview-in-hubsection) post for detail insight.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
<VirtualizingStackPanel> works well and now there are no gray ListView displayed.
But when I scroll down to bottom and scroll up and down again, 
"India" is deselected.